# When to call BeginAccept on a socket

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sockets

I have the following class in a Windows Service that is experiencing some vary strange shutdown behaviors. The server is shutting down from time-to-time with only this message in the event logs and no messages in the trace logs, "The Broadcaster service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s)."

```
Public Class ServerSocket
    Implements IServerSocket

    Public Event ClientConnected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs(Of IClientSocket)) Implements IServerSocket.ClientConnected

    Private _socket As Socket
    Private ReadOnly _settings As IBroadcasterServiceSettingsSection
    Private ReadOnly _traceSource As ITraceSource

    Public Sub New()
        Me.New(BroadcasterServiceSettingsSection.GetSection, BroadcasterTraceSource.Instance)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal settings As IBroadcasterServiceSettingsSection, ByVal traceSource As ITraceSource)
        _settings = settings
        _traceSource = traceSource
    End Sub

    Public Sub Listen() Implements IServerSocket.Listen
        Dim endPoint As New IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(_settings.BroadcasterIPAddress), _settings.BroadcasterPortNumber)
        Try
            _socket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
            _socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1)
            _socket.Bind(endPoint)
            _socket.Listen(SocketOptionName.MaxConnections)
            _socket.BeginAccept(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf AcceptCallback), Nothing)
            _traceSource.TraceInformation("ServerSocket listening for new clients.")
        Catch ex As Exception
            _traceSource.TraceCritical("ServerSocket caughtException trying to wait for a new client.")
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' First attempts to shutdown the socket to clean up any remaining data left to send or receive. Then closes
    ''' the socket to release all connections and clean up unmanaged resources. See also <seealso cref="System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Shutdown">Socket.Shutdown</seealso>
    ''' and <seealso cref="System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Close">Socket.Close</seealso>
    ''' </summary>

    Public Sub Close() Implements IServerSocket.Close
        Try
            _socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both)
        Catch ex As Exception
            _traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, "Shutting down Server Socket caused an exception.", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
        End Try

        Try
            _socket.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            _traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, "Closing the Server Socket caused an exception.", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
        End Try

        _traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, "ServerSocket closed.")
    End Sub

    Private Sub AcceptCallback(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
        Dim s As Socket = Nothing

        Try
            s = _socket.EndAccept(ar)
        Catch ex As Exception
            _traceSource.TraceInformation("ServerSocket caught exception trying to get new socket for client.", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
        End Try

        Try
            ' call the begin accept as soon as possible so that I can get the next incoming client 
            _socket.BeginAccept(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf AcceptCallback), Nothing)
        Catch ex As Exception
            _traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Critical, "ServerSocket caughtException trying to wait for a new client.", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace)
        End Try

        Try
            If s IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim clientSocket As IClientSocket = New ClientSocket(s)
                OnClientConnected(New EventArgs(Of IClientSocket)(clientSocket))
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            _traceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Critical, "9/23 Review: " + ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnClientConnected(ByVal e As EventArgs(Of IClientSocket))
        RaiseEvent ClientConnected(Me, e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

One thing about this class that stands out to me is that immediately after _socket.EndAccept is called _socket.BeginAccept is called and after that the work with the "Client Socket" is done. I can't put my finger on it but this just doesn't smell right. Should the socket that is being used to listen for new connections be kept as a field? If not, how would you call shutdown on it later? This is a very long running (weeks/months) process.

Comment: Capture your memory usage, in the end of each hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the async `Accept` works is that you typically issue `BeginAccept` immediately after accepting one connection, so you are ready for another incoming connection attempt.  I think the flow here is quite typical - when you get the callback for the first incoming connection, you issue `EndAccept` to complete it and then issue another `BeginAccept` to keep the listening socket ready for the next.

You will use the socket `s` for subsequent I/O on the first incoming connection, so you do need to keep that around.  the logic that does that is the setup of `clientSocket` using `s` as a parameter.

`_socket` is the one your code uses to listen for all incoming connections.

There's a detailed description of how this is all supposed to be done [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bb431f9.aspx).

I can't see any problems here with the socket handling logic.  I suggest you attach a debugger to your service and try to work out what is the context at the time of exit.

Comment: Attaching the debugger is a catch-22. The service doesn't fail quickly. It may run for 4 weeks or 4 hours and then out of the blue it will just dissapear. No error in the error log and no error in the trace log.

Answer (score 1):

The posted code do not cause any unhandled exceptions that can shutdown your server. Well, it does, but only in Listen.

Also, do not write `Throw ex`, it destroys the original stacktrace. `Throw` is enough.

As for EndAccept/BeginAccept/HandleEvent, there is nothing wrong with that.